# How to have a user select a file and what to do with that file in Python

Tags: python

How would I go about having a user choose a file and whether the write, read, or append the text in that file? Currently I'm trying this for the append, and it just gives the "not a valid number" and "not a valid filename" texts.

```
def fileAppend():
  try:
    file = input('What file do you want to append?')
    infile = open(file, 'a')
    try:
        numbers = input(int('What number do you want to put into the file?'))
        infile.write(numbers)
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a valid number.')
        numbers = input(int('What number do you want to put into the file?'))
    infile.close()
  except:
    print('Sorry, that is not a valid filename.')
```

Comment: `numbers = input(int('What number do you want to put into the file?'))` will always error out since its converting a sentence into an int ...

Comment: You shouldn't place the second input in the except clause. What happens if the user enters again a non-integer. Instead you probably should use a loop

Comment: You have not shared the code for what is contained in variable `file` and on which OS you are running the script. Secondly `input(int('What number do you want to put into the file?'))` this will complain as you are trying to convert a character string to integer rather you should convert the values coming in `int( input('What number do you want to put into the file?'))`

Comment: Instead of opening and closing the file, you should use the 'with' statement. (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: just put : numbers = input('What number do you want to put into the file?'), if you dont want to do any operations with that number ,write it like a string

Answer (score 0):

- If you're on Windows, the slashes in your filename need to be backslashes.
- Instead of `input(int())`, you need to write `int(input())`. Right now, it's trying to convert `'What number do you want to put into the file?'` into an integer, rather than the user input.